# Jetpack Compose Diagnostics - composeCompilerMetrics, composeCompilerReports

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I found the documentation which recommends using this code

```
subprojects {
  tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            if (project.findProperty("composeCompilerReports") == "true") {
                freeCompilerArgs += [
                        "-P",
                        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=" +
                                project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_compiler"
                ]
            }
            if (project.findProperty("composeCompilerMetrics") == "true") {
                freeCompilerArgs += [
                        "-P",
                        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:metricsDestination=" +
                                project.buildDir.absolutePath + "/compose_compiler"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in order to generate reports and metrics about `composable classes`.

In order to generate metrics (`stable`, `unstable`...) i used this command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -PcomposeCompilerMetrics=true
```

And it generates those reports into the `build/compose_compiler` folder

I also tried running the other one:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -PcomposeCompilerReports=true
```

But I can't really find where those reports are generated.
Where can i find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reports are still in the `app/build/compose_compiler` folder. However, you have to make sure that:

1. the script you posted, is included in the root's `build.gradle` file
2. you invoke the gradle command specifying the `:app:` module, like for instance

./gradlew :app:assembleRelease -PcomposeCompilerReports=true

Tested with gradle 8.4